# XGBoost in R gives every instance the same probability and not improving

Tags: r, classification, xgboost

I'm trying to predict whether or not an airline will add a route to their existing network by looking at their previous additions and training the model on what the previous year looked like. I've used xgboost before and it worked fine, but I removed a few cities and now xgboost is just predicting everything to be 50:50.

```
    trainm <- sparse.model.matrix(add ~. -1, data = train)
    train_label <- train[, "add"]
    train_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(data = (trainm), label = train_label)

    testm <- sparse.model.matrix(add~. -1, data = test)
    test_label <- test[, "add"]
    test_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(data = (testm), label = test_label)

    nc <- length(unique(train_label))
    xgb_params <- list("objective" = "binary:logistic",
                       "eval_metric" = "error",
                       "scale_pos_weight" = weight)
    watchlist <- list(train = train_matrix, test = test_matrix)

    bst_model <- xgb.train(params = xgb_params,
                           nthreads = 2,
                           data = train_matrix, 
                           nrounds = 10, 
                           watchlist = watchlist,
                           booster = 'gbtree'
                           )
```

outputs:

```
     [1]    train-error:0.972469    test-error:0.972580 
     [2]    train-error:0.972469    test-error:0.972580 
     [3]    train-error:0.972469    test-error:0.972580 
     [4]    train-error:0.972469    test-error:0.972580 
     [5]    train-error:0.972469    test-error:0.972580 
     [6]    train-error:0.972469    test-error:0.972580 
     [7]    train-error:0.972469    test-error:0.972580 
     [8]    train-error:0.972469    test-error:0.972580 
     [9]    train-error:0.972469    test-error:0.972580 
     [10]   train-error:0.972469    test-error:0.972580
```

It is weighted because it is very imbalanced (~36 negative for every 1 positive) just don't know why it's suddenly not working.

Edit. It fixed itself and I have no idea why.

Edit2. It did it again and I have no idea why.

Edit3. I fixed it. It has to do with NA values in certain columns.

Comment: What did you choose for `weight`

Comment: weight = 1.0/mean(full$add)  where

add is binary where 1 is the positive class.

Comment: did you figure it out?